# How to play the next and prev song of my music player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hi I'm develop a music player and I need play the next and previos song when I click the correct button.

I have 3 songs from raw directory and I have some methods but it starts from the first position and not from the actual position

here is my code

```
ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp; ;

int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorador);

play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay_Pause);
listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lv);

list = new ArrayList<>();

Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    list.add(fields[i].getName());
}


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, list);
listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        if(mp != null ){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }

        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Explorador.this, resID);
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

}

and my methods next and previos

```
public void Next(View view){
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    posicion = (posicion + 1)%list.size();
    int u = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(posicion), "raw", getPackageName());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mp.start();

}

public void Anterior(View view){
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    posicion = (posicion - 1 < 0)? list.size() - 1: posicion-1;
    int u = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(posicion), "raw", getPackageName());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: you are not initialising position variable when playing the media file

Comment: posicion=0 always when clicking the next and previous method first time

Comment: set posicion = i in onItemClickListener

Comment: Still doesn't work :( it close the app when I press button next

Comment: change the condition for next  make it similar to previous

Comment: post the error u r getting

Comment: It works now thanks!

Comment: Nice happy to hear

Comment: What did you did to fix it post it as answer

Comment: I change my initial value in int posicion=0; to int posicion; 
and also i did what you say in the method onClick of my listview i put posicion = i
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set posicion =i in onitemclick listener.
as posicion variable seems to have default value.